# In WordPress how do I change the tinyMCE Formats dropdown hover color?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

The color is currently a dark blue, and it's being picked up by the site's menu hover - I've tried various CSS rules, like ".mce-menu-item a:hover" but can't get any of them to work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your site or some kind of demo?

Comment: Sure, please see the screen shot jpg here: http://serra.cirrusvps.ca/formats.jpg - as you can see the dark blue rollover is so dark you can't read the text - I would like to change that color to something much lighter.

Comment: I mean something I can work with in real time, in my case image is not enough